# Laravel parent/children relationship on it's own model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, relationship

I want to get all the vouchers that have at least one child, a voucher can have multiple voucher children, but any voucher can only have one parent.

I set it up with the following models and calls, and the query it generates is as desired, until this part: `'vouchers'.'parent_id' = 'vouchers'.'id'`

**Wanted functionality:**

```
$vouchers = Voucher::has('children')->get();
```

or

```
$vouchers = Voucher::has('parent')->get();
```

**Resulted Query**

```
select * from `vouchers` where `vouchers`.`deleted_at` is null 
and (select count(*) from `vouchers` where `vouchers`.`deleted_at` is null 
and `vouchers`.`parent_id` = `vouchers`.`id` 
and `vouchers`.`deleted_at` is null ) >= 1
```

**Models:**

```
class Voucher extends baseModel {

    public function parent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Voucher', 'parent_id');
        // return $this->belongsTo('Voucher', 'parent_id', 'id'); <- attempted but din't work
    }

    public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Voucher', 'parent_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: I’ve used this parent–children method on models before. What problems are you having?

Comment: That it returns nothing. Even if I take the query generated by Laravel and run it directly on the database.

Comment: Due to this section `and 'vouchers'.'parent_id' = 'vouchers'.'id'` -- It's referencing itself in that subquery.  The outer query needs an alias on `vouchers`.

Comment: Are you able to use a Pivot table?

Comment: This issue has been reported and fixed in 5.0 https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/8193 Unfortunately there is no back port for the version 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been reported and fixed in 5.0 https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/8193

Unfortunately there is no back port for the version 4.

However if you want to apply the fix yourself you can see the list of modifications here : https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/8193/files

Be carefull, modifying the framework's code base is at risk but there will be no more bug fixes on Laravel 4.x version, only security fixes for a few more month.